# Relative Path em VBScript

Tags: xml, path, vbs

Quero associar um `XML` à uma aplicação em `VBScript` e preciso indicar na aplicação qual é o diretório onde deverá ler o `XML`, no entanto, como é fácil de prever, o `Path` do `XML` não pode ser hardcoded.

Existe alguma forma de em `VBScript` indicar `"../PastaAplicacao/Ficheiros/config.xml"` com `VBScript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tanto pegar o path do arquivo e tratar:

```vb
Dim caminhoArquivo, segmentosCaminhoArquivo, nomeArquivo, caminhoPastaAtual

caminhoArquivo = Wscript.ScriptFullName
segmentosCaminhoArquivo = Split(caminhoArquivo, "\")

nomeArquivo = segmentosCaminhoArquivo(UBound(segmentosCaminhoArquivo))
caminhoPastaAtual = Left(caminhoArquivo, Len(caminhoArquivo) - Len(nomeArquivo))
```

Ou até mesmo pegar o diretório atual ao instanciar um objeto:

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”)

caminhoPastaAtual = objShell.CurrentDirectory
```

A partir daí, você pode usar o caminho relativo com:

```vb
caminhoOutraPasta = caminhoPastaAtual & "..\pastaIrma\"
caminhoOutraPasta2 = caminhoPastaAtual & "pastaFilha"
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/